# нужно открывать приложение Viber, которое установлено на смартфоне

Tags: java, c#, android, unity3d

я использую Unity2020, и мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку в моем приложении, запускать Viber, вот C# код, который я использую для этого:

```
   public class LaunchAppFromMyOS : MonoBehaviour
{
public Button button;
public GameObject ButtonObject;
public string package = "ca-app-pub-3584055122541491~1878022797";
private void Start()
{
    button.GetComponent<Button>();
    button.onClick.AddListener(StartPackage);
 }

private void StartPackage()
{
    AndroidJavaClass activityClass;
    AndroidJavaObject activity, packageManager;
    AndroidJavaObject launch;
   


    activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    activity = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    packageManager = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
    launch = packageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage", package);
    activity.Call("startActivity", launch);
  }
}
```

в переменной package - идентификатор приложения. Но когда я нажимаю на кнопку - абсолютно ничего не происходит... может кто-то может подсказать, в чем проблема? заранее спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш комментарий! поправил!

Comment: _абсолютно ничего не происходит_ - хм... на java этот код выбросил бы исключение. В переменной `package` должен быть app-id **вайбера**, то что у вас в вопросе совсем не оно. Находим нужное приложение в маркете и в адресной строке видим его id `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip`, либо лезем в его APK и смотрим в манифесте атрибут `package`. То есть для вайбера это будет `com.viber.voip`. И перед запуском нужно убедиться что он есть на устройстве (`getLaunchIntentForPackage` должен вернуть `null` при отсутствии)

Comment: понял, спасибо Вам, woesss!