# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='onCreate' signature='()V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, c#, android, unity3d, плагин

У меня есть Unity приложение, которое использует java плагин. Вот мой java класс:

```
   public class MyLibrary extends Activity 
  {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       startActivity(intent);
   }

  }
```

этот код должен открывать приложение камеры на моем смартфоне Android. Итак, в моем приложении Unity есть кнопка, которая вызывает java-метод ... Когда я нажимаю кнопку, у меня есть это в logcat:

```
 2021-05-01 22:20:15.010 15532-15576/? E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no 
non-static method with name='onCreate' signature='()V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='onCreate' signature='()V' in class 
Ljava.lang.Object;
at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.getMethodID(Unknown Source:162)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$300(Unknown Source:0)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:95)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:20)
at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr clazz, System.IntPtr methodID, 
UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

вот мой C# код:

```
public class StartPluginToLoadCameraByButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button button;
    public GameObject ButtonOjbect;


   private void Start()
  {

      button = GetComponent<Button>();
      button.onClick.AddListener(StartPlugin);
  }

   public void StartPlugin()
  {

    var plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.workinglibrary.MyLibrary");
    plugin.Call("onCreate");

  }

}
```

после того как я не нашел решения моей проблемы в интернете, я задал этот вопрос на stackoverflow англ. версии, и там мне посоветовали сделать следующее: 1) заменить  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  на public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  2) также в то время когда я вызываю мой java метод из C# скрипта, я вызываю просто по названию метода, но в моем java скрипте он принимает один аргумент... в официальной документации юнити написано: public void Call(string methodName, params object[] args);  - ну первое это имя функции, а второе - это аргумент... Здесь у меня тоже возникла проблема, так как я не понимаю как правильно записать onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) в C#... видел как вызывают просто методы, без аргументов, но здесь не так... пожалуйста, мне бы пример увидеть, как этот аргумент записывать вместе с вызовом метода, и поможет ли это вообще решить эту ошибку что у меня в logcat? заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я конечно не шарю в шарпах с юнитами, но с точки зрения Андроида, ваш класс - это активность и для правильной её работы, она должна быть запущена интентом. При прямом создании её экземпляра и вызове методов - активность не "живая" с точки зрения системы, и ту задачу, которую вы хотите реализовать она не выполнит.

Comment: В общем случае, чтобы получить снимок с камеры, а не просто её открыть - нужна живая активность, так как результат работы камеры будет передан её методу `onActivityResult()`. То есть два варианта - запустить этот класс как новый экран (активити), либо наследовать его от `UnityPlayerActivity`, заменить в манифесте запись оной на свой класс-наследник и в нём реализовать все подобные задачи

Comment: Здравствуйте, woess! спасибо за Ваши комментарии! на данном этапе мне нужно просто открывать приложение камера на моем смартфоне. Можно уточнение по " нужна живая активность" - это значит что в java классе у меня по мимо метода который открывает камеру должны быть еще другие методы(основная активность)? Еще раз спасибо!=)

Comment: или это что-то типа этого: Activity activity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;

Comment: Да нужно её запустить как в том вопросе. Но если камеру нужно просто запустить - вы можете сделать это прямо из шарпа подобным же кодом. То есть вместо своей активити запустить напрямую активити камеры.

Comment: Все, понял=) спасибо Вам за Ваши ответы=) осталось решить мою проблему C# кодом)

Comment: Ещё как вариант, вы можете использовать код из своего вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1273812/11515, только убрать наследование `extends AppCompatActivity` и запуск сделать через активность юнитов: `UnityPlayer.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);` С колбеком, правда мне не понятно как это будет работать, но без него должно получиться

Comment: ого=) спасибо))) то есть убираю extends AppCompatActivity и вместо этого ставлю... extends Activity или extends UnityPlayerActivity? и получается уже эта реализация даст тоже простой запуск камеры вместо моей основной активности?

Comment: Вообще ничего не нужно наследовать - просто убрать. А вот когда захотите обратную связь (то есть снимок) тогда  `extends UnityPlayerActivity`, но там вроде как уже не всё так просто

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное, woess!=)  я рад:)

Comment: если тебе не помогут вышеперечисленные указания(про активити), то также проверь кое какие галочки: Player Settings > Publishing Settings > секция Minify > убери галочки с R8, Debug, Release

Comment: спасибо Вам Methorn! галочки были убраны! пока что пытаюсь исправить ошибку, которую я получаю при компиляции моего юнити проекта... о результатах отпишу)

Comment: а нельзя ли как-то запустить камеру не применяя плагин? только с помощью языка C#? я помню что например приложения скачанные из play market можно только с помощью C# запускать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1271715/%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-viber-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5?noredirect=1#comment2238624_1271715